# Informatica Cloud Target file column order

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

I am using informatica cloud to create a target output by combining three mappings. I am facing an issue while writing the records to a target file. The target file is being created at run time. There are around 350 columns in total. Out of this, around 20 columns are static and others are dynamic. But the columns in the target files are not displaying in a proper order. In the `"Field Mapping"` the columns are displaying in a order, but in output file it is displaying in a different order.

Is there a way to create the target file output columns in a specific order. I mean at least certain static columns in a specific order? I know we can attain this by using a template file. But I can not create a template file as certain columns are dynamic. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you not chnage the order by going to `Target properties > Target Fields` ?

Comment: The target file is being generated dynamically and on the fly

Comment: hmm, there must be some logic that controls the sequence of fields -you can check that.